Best approach for creating an accessible multi-step form with aria-live step indicator?
I'm working on a multi-step form where each step is dynamically displayed using <template> elements. As the user progresses, the previous step is hidden, and the next step is revealed (with JavaScript).
For accessibility, I’ve added aria-live="polite" to the root of the HTML document, and I dynamically update the content based on the selected step using JavaScript.
My question is: which approach is more accessible?

Adding aria-live="polite" to the root element and updating it with JavaScript when the step changes.

OR

Adding aria-live="polite" to each <template> element, with the step title already included inside the template.


<template> are just like <script> not rendered in DOM, I don't think screen readers detect them at all.

Neither option is recommended. You generally don't want turn large areas of content into a live region. It is somewhat hard to give a good answer without seeing the project, but one solution might be to have a heading at the beginning of each step, add tabindex="-1" to the heading, and programmatically place focus on the heading when the new step appears. No aria-live required.

If a large aria-live region was configured with aria-relevant="additions" would that work the same as moving the focus?

No. If you announce the content of a form but don't move focus to it, it won't help much, it could even confuse the user because you can think you are somewhere when you aren't in fact. As said in the answer, handle the focus correctly and you should be good. It's a lot more important. Big aria-live regions aren't recommended because very often, the whole content is read in one go without interruption, and it might even freeze the screen reader for a while if it's very big.
